# How to merge two ffmpeg queries to one pipe?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a sequence (100 images) (image ex: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8HwOuIo9PBX3ix0eKFQFGimskU_H0mN/view?usp=sharing) of Bayer images, what I need to do is

1. debayer them
2. compress the result in the `.h264` file

So, there are two queries that I use

for debayer

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time%7d_img.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: -hide_banner | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size 4104x3006 -i pipe: -frames 100 D:\Buffer\res\result%7d.png -hide_banner
```

and for compression

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i D:\Buffer\res\result%7d.png -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 D:\Buffer\res264\test5.h264 -hide_banner
```

I need to merge these two queries into one, I tried to do it like this

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time%7d_img.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: -hide_banner | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size 4104x3006 pipe: -hide_banner | ffmpeg -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -i pipe D:\Buffer\res264\test5.h264 -hide_banner
```

but I get an error here

```
Input #0, image2, from 'D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time%7d_img.bmp':
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':  Duration:
00:00:40.0Output file #0 does not contain any stream0
, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/AUnknown decoder 'hevc_nvenc'

    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, pal8, 2464x2056, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray, 2464x2056, q=2-31, 1013196 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=    4947kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=1013196.8kbits/s speed=   2x
video:4947kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
Conversion failed!
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note: We are going to be down-voted, because there are users that think this is not a programming question, and should not be posted in Stack Overflow (don't take it personally). I think it is a programming question, because the question is asked to be answered by a programmer.

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168740/are-ffmpeg-questions-really-off-topic) post, it supposed to be asked in Super User.

Comment: @Rotem ok, got it. By the way, do you use it (SU)?

Comment: I asked one question in SU (a question regarding FFmpeg), but never answered.

Comment: The downvoting on my answers and associated questions has increased since last month; seemingly due to a particular user. Questions about the programmatic usage of the FFmpeg libav* libraries are on-topic for Stack Overflow. Officially, most ffmpeg command-line questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow. But in reality SO has failed at enforcing any distinction so it is now a general computing question site. These questions should be asked at [su] if you want to avoid the downvoters or avoid getting your question closed. I see all ffmpeg questions at [su] too and answer if I can.

Comment: *"seemingly due to a particular user"* As suggested by the automated reversal of some of the serial downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few notes:

- There is no need to convert the frames to PNG first.
- `hevc_nvenc` applies H.265 codec, and you are using `.h264` file extension.
  I tried `h264_nvenc`, but I got an error, because the resolution is too high (for H.264 NVIDIA encoder).
- `result%7d.png` should be `result%07d.png`
- It is recommended to select the pixel format (yuv420p or yuv444p).

Here is the syntax:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i Time%07d_img.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -framerate 30 -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size 4104x3006 -i pipe: -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv444p test5.hevc
```

Comment: actually, I thought that `hevc_nvenc` is `.h264`... ok, I see.

Comment: I posted the question here in `SuperUser` maybe you know the answer (it has an additional points) https://superuser.com/q/1652705/678484