# ffmpeg makes video upside down when using overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm adding an overlay to a video. The video is correct before run the command below and the output is a flipped video upside down. The overlay is correct, but the video flips.

The command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input_video.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output_video_with_overlay.mp4
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I suspect rotation metadata. Showing the complete log from the command will verify.

Answer (score -1):

If someone is facing the same problem, it happens when concatenating videos with different resolutions and then try to add overlay. My fix was to resize all videos before concatenate and then add the overlay. Now it works.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602142/how-to-merge-two-ffmpeg-queries-to-one-pipe#comment119498592_67602142) regarding the downvoting.

Comment: So, I should add it with my PHP code that performs the video concatenation and adds the overlay. Then it would be consider as a programming question.

Comment: It would probably still be downvoted as the PHP is unrelated to the actual issue (which is that ffmpeg automatically rotates video according to the metadata). Best to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when possible.